# Is there a way to convert a bool to a string?

Tags: c++, string, boolean

I need to convert a bool to a text string. Does anyone know how to do that?

I tried to use `(std::string)bool` syntax but it didn't work.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Well, given that a `bool` can only be two possible values, don't you think it's pretty simple to brute force it? If it's true, set the string to "yup", otherwise set it to "nope". An `if` statement, or the ternary operator should do the trick, right?

Comment: Something like `std::string result = your_bool?  "true result" : "false result";` will do it.   Substitute whatever your program needs for `"true result"` and `"false result"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard does not define any direct conversions between `bool` and `std::string` at the language level.

The simplest option is to just do the conversion yourself, eg:

```
std::string s;
if (theBoolValue)
    s = "true";
else
    s = "false";
```

Or:

```
std::string s = theBoolValue ? "true" : "false";
```

On the other hand, if you want to use the standard library to do the conversion, there are options for that.

`operator<<` and `operator>>` for I/O streams can convert between `bool` and `std::string`. For instance, you can use a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to format a `bool` into a `std::string`, eg:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << theBoolValue;
std::string s = oss.str();
```

By default, that will output `"1"` for `true` and `"0"` for `false`.  If you want the output to actually say `"true"` or `"false"` instead, you can use the [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) I/O manipulator, eg:

```
oss << std::boolalpha << theBoolValue;
```

Alternatively, in C++20 and later, you can use [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) (in earlier versions, you can use the [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev) library), eg:

```
std::string s = std::format("{}", theBoolValue); // returns "true" or "false"
```

```
std::string s = std::format("{:L}", theBoolValue); // returns the locale-specific representation
```

```
std::string s = std::format("{:d}", theBoolValue); // returns "1" or "0"
// other supported numeric formats:
// {:b} and {:B} for binary, "0b..." lowercase and "0B..." uppercase
// {:o} for octet, "0..."
// {:x} and {:X} for hex, "0x..." lowercase and "0X..." uppercase
```

Comment: I suggest this is over-kill for converting a single `bool` value, but it is scalable to larger and non-trivial cases  (e.g. if there is a need to write a set of values string, using a string stream, including a `bool`).

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace vt {
  static constexpr auto as_string(const bool x) -> std::string {
    return (x) ? "true" : "false";
  }
} // namespace vt

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const auto x = argv[argc] != nullptr;
  // NB: argv[argc] is always nullptr so it's false.

  // Using a turnary to initialize a std::string
  // (See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)
  const auto k0 = std::string(x ? "true" : "false");
  std::cout << "k0 = std::string(x ? \"true\" : \"false\"):\t" << k0 << "\n";

  // Using a function to achieve the same.
  const auto k1 = vt::as_string(x);
  std::cout << "k1 = vt::as_string(x):\t\t\t" << k1 << "\n";

  // If you need a string but you're fine with "0"/"1" over "false"/"true"
  const auto k2 = std::to_string(x); // x is implicitly converted to int
  std::cout << "k2 = std::to_string(x):\t\t\t" << k2 << "\n";

  // If you only intend to write to a std::ostream you don't need a string.
  std::cout << "std::cout << std::boolalpha << x:\t"
            << std::boolalpha << x << std::endl;
}
```

[Live on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%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%2Bnrcr82cAaWJKyuBiUuc45KSJAMlPDERIfWR9QSrq/yuXlrkhdO0WDALSWhZjJX4pAVxaHqm5dQ%2BDgFloThE14PwOC0UhUE4SSrEsaElhWB4Nh4Ugsqt42FnwkBEw0fROEkXgWAkDQA8t63bY4XhnwDz2tAWOBYBgRAUEAxI6GichKDQB6s5ibZDGAXFqIYfDSCwQFnswAA1VzWwAeUQy33ZoWgvuIZ8IAiTReAiYJ6g7PvSAHtcO0biJtHaT33bzthBEbhg3pHrBHSMcQvcrvAeQ6dzny3lF2ixNZrftSoR6eiJiCHjwsBHs9Q69hYqAMYAFHrzAm5bzg29kEQxDsCkDIQQigVDqC3roBIkFjDWGsPoPAERnyQAWAhaoB8aSN1iLSNi2ZTCWGsGYIiNIADqYhaC0hISiKUTBeB/CKD5TgRIYHLmlOXXY9tCHEKwdSSKLBY6VBnukFwDB3CeGaCAMwAAOUggQpjFFKCAaQuQ0gCFGH4aRSQUiqIYL0BRAxpBtHsjUCY6jJEyKMdULoDQ9H9BiIY0x4jsiaJhDY%2BRdilELAHMsVYeh2yL0LE1Bg/A%2B4mzNhbEe0dmHF1YbZfCHC4GWCIbSHhOJ%2BEe1CaQCASA0E5yJBnAuoRGEcFUFIgAbDSMpkgEQsIgGXfCcxeDfUICQPATIEj8EEAA8QwDOnyCUGoEeUCkiGDCMU5ujgWD7lhOkXYn9WzRAEVUYREBXBmISHIooHiEgqOqOsrReR0i2JmDEVogjjHWMaE4loFRlkCEuccxR4xuj7NcZMLZJyJALCppgNpIANBhI4ObUgkdeDRwmXgKZe4ZkOXmYsjJz8fZ%2BwDqbDgwdSCh39iCyJnBY7/IRYnLJqdskgG5okLEeS86Z3oMQIpbBOClIqVUmpMS6lsIaU0/ARATjtJAcIUQPTpB9LAYMyBORRl0vYGSilxMmCJEyai4FoKbakqxOSggBLvakAwkwLAMQICAvRZiiOOKY62HxQnLVvssWotiBEre0deCWrmICsw9qo64s1S60gy1UjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer. But why did you declare `as_string` in such a complicated way?  Why not `std::string as_string(bool x) {return x?"true":"false";}`

Comment: That's just how I'm used to write functions. It's pretty arbitrary.
`auto foo(bool) -> string` (trailing return type) is —functionally— the same as `string foo(bool)`.
However since `std::string` is `constexpr`(as of C++20) it makes sense to add it (assuming your compiler supports it).

Answer (score 0):

This is what Sam Varshavchik suggested in comment,
basically, that is it:)

```
    bool b;
    std::string decoded; 
    ...
    
    decoded = b ? "true" : "false";
    printf("b is %s\n"
      , decoded.c_str()
      );
```

Comment: Well, I missed that, thank you. :)